# adding values to determine answer using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I asked this question a few days ago but I did a poor job of describing the specifics so I'm posting it again in greater detail.

Goal:
user to fill out survey with a list of questions and answers to choose from and the results would show a conditional page/div section based on the users selections.  If the user selects an answer that is of the same value more times then any other value then show specific content based on the users selection.  Here's a plunker that has the questions and answers.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FtL8arjcHPUEbs4r1BJS?p=preview

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="q in questions">
      <label>{{q}}</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="1" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="1">blue
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="1" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="2">red
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="1" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="3">grey
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>


<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="q1 in questions">
      <label>{{q1}}</label>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="2" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="1">something else
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="2" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="2">something in here
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="2" ng-model="formData[$index]" value="3">something  else in here
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>    


<button ng-click="stats()">show results</button>

    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(c, n) in results"> {{c}} shows {{n}} times</li>
    </ul>
```

right now I'm lacking the logic to show the conditional div content on the results page based on the users selections. 
I'm also down for other solutions to achieve this goal too.

thanks!

Comment: where are you having difficulty? i remember making a score aggregator for you that could be adjusted to change from color values you were using to numbers you are using now. Wouldn't that help you?

Comment: @charlietfl what you did was correct, but I'm having difficulty creating multiple questions with different answers. The values, however, can stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directives.

You need somethink like this:

```
<div ng-if="someFoo()">some content</div>
```

And in js:

```
$scope.someFoo = function () {
    return true; // or calculate any other results
}
```